# iOS Evernote SDK with Evernote App 8.x

Tags: ios, evernote

We have recently noticed that our app's Evernote integration has stopped working.  I've pinpointed it to the new Evernote app update released on January 19th that brings the app to version 8.0.1.  Specifically the "IsEvernoteInstalled()" function no longer works, and neither do any ENSession calls that open notes in the Evernote app itself (viewNoteInEvernote for example).  I made sure I have the latest version of the Evernote Cloud SDK here: 
https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios
but I'm still not having any luck.  One oddity I've noticed is that the only required LSApplicationQueriesSchemes item mentioned in the documentation is "en" yet the source code for the app is trying to open "evernote://" urls.  Also the "IsEvernoteInstalled" function checks "en://".  The current version of the Evernote iOS app appears to only have "evernote://" as a registered scheme so I'm confused.  I tried adding "evernote" as another application query scheme, but that did not help.  It appears that the Evernote Cloud SDK has not been updated to remain functional with the new version of the app, but maybe I'm missing something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the change of URL scheme is [unintentional](https://twitter.com/evernotehelps/status/822153493104435201) and will be fixed on the Evernote side.

Comment: Not sure how long it will take to get fixed, but just wanted to note that the "https://" URL scheme correctly opens notes in the Evernote v8 iOS app.  (Links have to go through the browser but they do work.)

Comment: I tested the just-released Evernote iOS beta 8.1 (build 352227) and that version successfully opens a note using the "evernote://" URL scheme, which previous iOS version 8 builds did not.